# Understanding a text in a book about the estimation

Tags: summation, special-functions

> Now
> $$e_n-e_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left [ -\frac{1}{12(k+x)^2}+\mathcal{O}\left ( \frac{1}{(k+x)^3} \right ) \right ]; \tag{*}$$
> therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n-e_0=K_1(x)$ exists. Set
> $$e_n=K(x)+\frac{1}{12(n+x)}+\mathcal{O}\left ( \frac{1}{(n+x)^2} \right ),$$
> where $K(x)=K_1(x)+e_0$. The term $(n+x)^{-1}$ comes from completing the sum in $(*)$ to infinity and approximating the added sum by an integral.

This is taken from a [book](https://books.google.dk/books?id=kGshpCa3eYwC&lpg=PP1&hl=da&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 19. This is about estimating a specific value (integral). I do not understand the two last sentences. Could you please explain it for me?

Answer (score 1):

They are using the Euler–Maclaurin formula which states that the approximation $$\sum_{i=n}^mf(i)\approx\int_n^mf(x)dx$$ holds (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) for further details) and combining it with the fact that $\sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i)$ is small for any convergent summation. So you can approximate the sum with it's "completed" infinite sum, and then approximate the infinite sum with it's integral.